# Recommended method for reloading `.zshrc`? (`source` VS `exec`?)

Tags: permissions, exec, zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

Most people seem to recommend using `source` for reloading `.zshrc`. Why?

First I tried out `source ~/.zshrc`. But it resulted in a `compinit` error (at reload, not for new shell instances at first `.zshrc` load).

My reload alias is now:

```
alias zsh-reload="exec zsh"
```

instead of:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

The reason for this is that my previous reload method (`source`) triggered a compinit error;

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

So I'm now doing `exec` because I believie it ensures the previous environment doesn't pollute the new one.

- What are the downsides of using the `exec` method?
- Is there an explicit reason for that you're doing `exec` or `source`?
- Could `exec` in theory cause unexpected problems compared to the `source` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `exec`, all (unexported) variables in your shell are lost, which is probably not what you want. Instead, it might be better to fix the compinit problem, by using `compinit -i`. See the zsh man page for *compinit*, paragraph *Use of compinit*:

> to  make compinit silently ignore all insecure files and directories  use  the  option  -i