# zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I get this when I tre to run the terminal on my mac:

> zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list.
> Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? y

Suggested answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762280/zsh-compinit-insecure-directories) are of no use to me as they all involve running commands which I'm not currently able to do. How do I resolve this?

Ths is my `.zshrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH:/Users/paulcarron/Apache/apache-maven-3.8.1/bin"
eval "$(jenv init -)"
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
    source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

`.bashrc`:

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
eval "$(jenv init -)"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
if [ -r ~/.zshrc ]; then
   source ~/.zshrc
fi
```

Comment: Why are you not able to run those commands?

Comment: Because I can't seem to exit out of `zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list. Ignore insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]? y`. Each time I select an option that just appears back in the terminal.

Comment: What, you mean that, when you press `y` or `n` in response to that question, then the same question pops up again?

Comment: What have you installed? This is not asked by default in `zsh` on macOS.

Comment: Yes. If I press y or n I get the question again. Not sure what might have been installed.

Comment: @runnerpaul : Configure your terminal, so that you can start tabs which run either `bash`  or a `zsh` that bypasses the usual startup files. This is always handy as a backup, even if you don't need it in your daily business. Another possibility is to use your text editor to comment out the `compinit` line in your startup file; at least this will give you a working shell from which you can proceed further.

Comment: @runnerpaul : See also my response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56284264/recommended-method-for-reloading-zshrc-source-vs-exec/56303297#56303297) question. While your problem is slightly different, my response should apply to your case as well.

Comment: @runnerpaul It would be useful if you could add your `.zshrc` file to your question.

Comment: @MarlonRichert `.zshrc` added to question.

Comment: Why do you `source ~/.bash_profile`? Please add the contents of that file to your question, too.

Comment: @MarlonRichert I can't remember why I added `source ~/.bash_profile` but think it was in order to resolve some other issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a created an infinite loop in your dotfiles. Your `.zshrc` sources your `.bashrc`, which sources your `.zshrc`, *ad infinitum.*

Additionally, when you source `"$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"` from `zsh`, [it for some strange reason calls `compinit`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/b6b6e685a39b9cc457a82530652b420d667c1dd1/bash_completion#L86). (This is something that `nvm` [should not do](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/2495).)

So, there you have it: Together, you’ve created yourself infinite `compinit`s.

Moral of the story: It’s already a bad idea to source `.bashrc` from `.zshrc`, or vice versa, but doing it in both directions is even worse.

Solution: Don’t do that and remove the offending lines from your dotfiles.